# dynamic programming - recursion

Tags: algorithms, recursion, dynamic-programming

We have $n$ requests to plant trees. Each request comes with a position $p_i$ which means we have to plant the tree $p_i$ meters away from a specific constant point. Also, there should not be another tree for $k_i$ meters from another tree. What is the max number of trees we can plant given that $p_i < p_{i+1}$?

I came up with the following for the recursion to solve subproblems $R(i)$ but I'm not sure if it is correct:

$$
R(1) = 1
$$

$R(i) = \max(R(j) + 1) $ if $ j < i $ and $ p_i - k_i > p_j$  and $p_j + k_j  < p_i$.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange, Please clarify a few things in you problem: Are these trees supposed to be planted over a straight line? In a 2D region? Is there a space constraint?

Comment: Does the subscript $i$ correspond to the $i$-th request, or does it refer to some prior ordering of the trees?

Comment: @avs R(i) is the solution to the subproblem where  1 <= i <= n.

Comment: @User2709, what about $p_{i}$?

Comment: @avs pi is the position for which the tree should be planted at according to the request

Comment: I was asking about the connection between the $i$ and the $p$.

Comment: @avs Oh sorry. it means that the i-th request asks us to plant a tree at position pi

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180859/dynamic-programming-largest-number-of-dams-that-can-be-built

Comment: @Cesareo thank you. It is basically the same question but they don't solve it using dynamic programming. I just want to know if my recursion is correct